# Segmentation fault while reading PPM

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fread, ppm

Could anybody please tell me why am I getting a segmentation fault when running this code? I am trying to open a PPM file with P6 format, on the second line there is its dimension, on the third line there is a 255 constant.
Below is a "2D array" of numbers representing each pixel. I know there are 3 numbers for each pixel (RGB) but I still want to have it all in 2D array (3 colors of one pixel next to each other)(thats why i am multiplying size[1] by 3), but I am getting a segmentation fault.

Thanks for help :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char*argv[]){

char *fname = argv[1];
FILE* f = fopen(fname, "r");
char format[3];
int size[2];

//reading image format
fscanf(f,"%s", format);
printf("%s\n", format);

//reading size
fscanf(f,"%d %d", size, size+1);
printf("%d %d\n", size[0], size[1]);

//reading a constant - 255
int Constant=0;
fscanf(f,"%d", &Constant);

//mallocating a 2D array to store individual pixels
uint8_t **array=malloc (3*size[1]*size[0]*sizeof(uint8_t));

//reading pixels from file and storing into array
for(int i=0 ; i<size[1]; i++){
  for(int j=0 ; j<size[0]*3 ; j++){
    fread(array, size[0]*size[1]*3 , 1, f);

  }
}

for(int k=0;k<size[1];k++){
  for(int l=0; l<size[0]*3; l++){
    printf("%d ", array[k][l]);
  }
printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fread(array, size[0]*size[1]*3 , 1, f);` will include the `newline` which follows `Constant` (255).

Comment: i am sort of a beginner , can you show me a better way to do it ?

Comment: I changed the previous comment after seeing you are using P6 format. But you must at least align the datya with the array.

Comment: i thought that if you just pass pointer to "array" it will put the elements there one by one. what do you exactly mean by aligning it there?

Comment: I mean that the `newline` after `255` is the next byte that will be read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t **array=malloc (3*size[1]*size[0]*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

This is not the good way to malloc a 2D array. You first have to malloc the number of "lines" in your array, then to malloc the number of "columns" for each line of your array.

Try replacing it by:

```
uint8_t **array = malloc(size[1] * sizeof(uint8_t*));
for (size_t i = 0; i < size[1]; ++i)
    array[i] = malloc(3 * size[0] * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

Comment: tried, still getting the Segm. fault.  now i really have no idea where the error could be

Comment: Try putting debug prints to know exactly where is the segmentation fault happening. In C, most of segmentation faults are due to allocation problems though.

Comment: so there is probably an issue with the third row from the bottom --- array[k][l] - because if i change it to something else like some constant for example it prints out a nice 10x30 array. event array [0][0] wont work (segm.fault)......

Answer (score 0):

I have it!!!!! the problem was in reading the elements of the file. it should look like

```
for(int i=0 ; i<size[1]; i++){
    for(int j=0 ; j<size[0]*3 ; j++){
       fread(*array, size[0]*size[1]*3 , 1, f);
    }
}
```